# Correctly calculating multiple choice

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms

I am developing a program that allows users to make their own Quiz and then send it to their employees.

Now one of the elements that i have is multiple choice (or multiple response if you like). However im facing some problems with this calculation.

So far ive only been able to come up with the following cases:

Case 1:

1 correct answer = 1 point

1 incorrect answer = -1 point

However this solution will not work as one question might be able to ruin the over all test. Because your actually able to affect other questions, and or get a negative score.

Case 2:

1 correct answer = 1 point

1 incorrect answer = 0

Once again this solution will not work either. With the above solution a tester would be able to click all answers as correct and get the maxium score.

Ive been searching around on google and this is actually a quite known problem. However i have been unable to find a solution that will suit the test i have.

So my question to you is, how should i go about this?

(Please note im not quite sure what to tag this as, feel free to edit my tags)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly are you trying to archive with your scoring system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I think you want to avoid is to make "choose everything" a viable option, yet not let false answered questions ruin the whole test.

**Solution 1:**

Do your case 1, i.e. correct answer implies 1 point, incorrect answer implies -1 point, however add the premisse that you will get $0$ points for the question if your total score is less than 0 for the question (thus you will never be punished for answering a question).

Cons: If you have a question with more correct answers than incorrect answers, just spamming answers will still bring you points.

**Solution 2:**

For each question let 
$$\text{negative points from a false answer=}\frac{\text{Sum points from correct answers}}{\text{number of false answers}}$$

thus each question will by default not give 0 points to those who just spam answers.

Cons: You will not be able to tell the testers how many points a false answers give (if they know how many points a correct answer give), as then they will be able to figure out how many false answers there are. Also sometimes a small mistake choosing a single false answer might result in many negative points.